# Staying on the active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with monthly worksheets.  One for Emails and one for Calls and I have created two userForms for data entry, one for Emails and one for Calls.

The forms do the job and they enter date in the right place but if I have selected the "August 18 Email" sheet and use the Email form, once the form is submitted it jumps to display the "August 18 Calls" sheet.

I just want it to stay in the selected worksheet, in this case "August 18 Email".

The code for the Emails form is the one below and the one for the Calls is nearly the same but only changing this line :   `Set ws = Sheets(Format(Date, "mmmm yy") & " calls")`

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ws = Sheets(Format(Date, "mmmm yy") & " emails")


lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    If Me.txtDateBox.Value = "" Then
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mmm/yy")
    Else
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDateBox.Value
    End If

 myVar = ""

For x = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox2.Selected(x) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.ListBox2.List(x, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & "," & Me.ListBox2.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next x

.Cells(lRow, 11).Value = myVar



myVarSign = ""

For x = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox3.Selected(x) Then
        If myVarSign = "" Then
            myVarSign = Me.ListBox3.List(x, 0)
        Else
            myVarSign = myVarSign & "," & Me.ListBox3.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next x

.Cells(lRow, 12).Value = myVarSign

myVarTheme = ""

For x = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(x) Then
        If myVarTheme = "" Then
            myVarTheme = Me.ListBox1.List(x, 0)
        Else
            myVarTheme = myVarTheme & "," & Me.ListBox1.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next x

.Cells(lRow, 14).Value = myVarTheme

    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.Time.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.ComboBox15.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.ComboBox6.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.ComboBox7.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.ComboBox11.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 15).Value = Me.ComboBox16.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
End With

Me.txtDateBox.Value = ""
Me.Time.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox4.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox5.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox6.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox7.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox11.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox16.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox15.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""

Dim iCount As Integer

For iCount = 0 To Me!ListBox1.ListCount
    Me!ListBox1.Selected(iCount) = False
Next iCount

 For iCount = 0 To Me!ListBox2.ListCount
    Me!ListBox2.Selected(iCount) = False
Next iCount

 For iCount = 0 To Me!ListBox3.ListCount
    Me!ListBox3.Selected(iCount) = False
Next iCount


End Sub
```

It could be improved a lot but I am happy if after submission the worksheet in view stays instead to jumping to another one.

As you can see I am only beginning (I have managed to create this with help of others).

Comment: I am not seeing anything in that code that will change the sheet you are looking at. I am thinking it may be code listed in the userform code.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove any instances of `.Select` or `.Activate` on worksheet, range, or cell objects, your sheet shouldn't change.

If that is not an option, another solution would be to note what sheet you are on when the code is called and then `Activate` that sheet before ending your sub. Since we do not see all of the userform code, you will have to strategically decide where this goes (as mentioned by @K.Davis, nothing shown switches the sheet so it must be happening in some other code).

---

When the macro/userform is launched:

```
Dim StartSheet as Worksheet
Set StartSheet = ActiveSheet
```

Then, before exiting macro/userform:

```
StartSheet.Activate
```

You may have to pass this along as a parameter depending on how your code is structured.

Comment: Thanks @K.Davis and urdearboy  I will have a look at the code at the end of the day as now the workbook is shared and cannot access the macros until everyone stops using it.